# Validation Rule salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I would love to have someone assist me with this task:
In the standard "Account" object, I need to create a Validation Rule that allows user to
change "Type" to "Customer – Direct" only if the account has at least 1 child
Opportunity in stage "Closed Won" (I can create whatever help fields/values
I need for this purpose).
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Trailhead has a [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) to get you started learning Validation Rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update){
   for(Account Acc: Trigger.New)
   {
        Opportunity opportunityData = [select id, AccountId, StageName from 
                                      Opportunity where StageName ='Closed Won' 
                                       And AccountId =:Acc.Id limit 1];
        if(Acc.Type == 'Customer - Direct' && opportunityData == null)
        { 
             Acc.addError('Enter Your Error Message');
        }
   }
```

}